# Question on retreival of only subset of data record from a table using NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

Suppose there is **table (Tbl_Test)** with 7 **columns A,B,C,D,E,F,G** and similarly there is an **Entity class** with all these as its **attributes a,b,c,d,e,f,g.**

If I query the table using Nhibernate to fetch a record:

**IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("select I.A, I.B, I.C from Tbl_Test I where I.D :xyz");**

> "Suppose there is only one record in
>   the table with D column's value as
>   some XYZ"

Now what will be the value of the attributes of the entity class.

**Will the attributes apart from a,b,c (that is the attributes d,e,f and g) will have the value as null for the fetched object.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IQuery q = session.CreateQuery ("select new MyEntityView(a, b, c) from Entity");
```

where

- MyEntityView is a class you create which has properties to hold those values that you want to retrieve.  Also, you must make sure that this class has an appropriate constructor
- Entity is the full-fledged Entity that you've mapped.

You can also achieve this by using the ICriteria API.
I've elaborated more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347302/two-classes-mapped-to-same-tableone-readonly-must-be-in-correct-order/1367717#1367717).